# If I create a List of XElements out of an XDocument, is a new copy of the element list created in memory?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, memory-management, linq-to-xml

If I have an `XDocument` loaded in memory from an `XDocument.Load` and then I do a LINQ-XML query on it such as:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:/doc.xml");
var orders = doc.Root.Element("Envelope").Elements("Order");
```

Is there an in-memory copy of the `IEnumerable<XElement>` returned by the second line?  Or is it just a reference copy to the original `XDocument`

What about if I actually enumerate it by calling `.ToList()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XDocument.Load` will read the entire dataset into memory.

Queries over the data will return references to existing elements.  For example, check the reference source for [GetElement](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/XLinq.cs#2985), which `yield`s existing nodes to the caller directly (by reference).

The main additional memory generated as you query the document would be the memory required to implement the iterators themselves, which should be exceedingly minor compared to the document size.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference.

You would have to use the `new` operator to allocate memory to a new `List<XElement>` on the heap.

Comment: `XElement` is a reference type. It will be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an in-memory copy of the IEnumerable returned by the second line? Or is it just a reference copy to the original XDocument

As others pointed out, its the latter.

In case you do want a Deep Clone of the element, you can use the [`XElement` copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297950(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ordersCopy = doc.Root.Element("Envelope").Elements("Order").Select(element => new XElement(element);
```